# Format a column automatically to convert whatever is entered to all capitals

Tags: excel-2011

One of the columns in my Excel spreadsheet is just three letter codes that all need to be in capital letters.

So I don't have to worry about making sure each time I enter one of the codes that I have Caps Lock on, how can I make Excel automatically convert everything that I enter in that one column from cell B2 until forever to always be in capitals?

Answer (score 0):

Excel will not convert lower case to upper automatically. The obvious solution would be with something like VBA but since not tagged as such a couple of alternatives are:

1. Use a caps only font (eg [Gothic](http://www.myfonts.com/fonts/woodentypefonts/gothic/))
2. Enter either but then apply a formula for the conversion, eg:

   ```
   =UPPER(B2)
   ```

So whether B2 is entered as `abc`, or `aBc` or `abC` the result would be `ABC`.